# "ByteArrayBasedCursorStreamProvider cannot be cast to HttpRequestAttributes" when trying to set attributes before APIKit

Tags: http-headers, mule, dataweave, mule4, apikit

I have a requirement on my REST API where I might set some attributes before APIKit if some condition is met (because we have a logger which must write this information).

Following [this](https://mulesoftprm.force.com/s/question/0D52T00005So5i0SAB/how-do-i-change-a-header-value-in-the-attributs) solution, I created the script below to set Attribute object inside Transform component.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(
    (attributes 
        - "headers"
        - "maskedRequestPath")
    ++
    ({ 
        headers: attributes.headers 
        ++ 
        { 
            xpto: 123
        }
    }) 
)
as Object {
    class: "org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes"
}
```

However, I am getting `org.mule.weave.v2.el.ByteArrayBasedCursorStreamProvider cannot be cast to org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes` error.

Is there a way where I can successfully set these values before APIKit Router?

I am using APIKit v1.6.1, with 4.3.0 runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `output application/java` in order to create an HttpAttributes

Comment: hello @machaval, thanks for your answer, it worked! now I have a more complex requisite, and asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120074/errors-while-creating-serializablelazyvalue-by-reflection-when-trying-to-set-s glad if u could help too!