# "Errors while creating SerializableLazyValue by reflection" when trying to set secure property as attribute before APIKit

Tags: http-headers, mule, dataweave, mule4, apikit

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112645/bytearraybasedcursorstreamprovider-cannot-be-cast-to-httprequestattributes-whe) question, I must set some attributes before APIKit. However, one of them is a secure property:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
(
    (attributes 
        - "headers"
        - "maskedRequestPath")
    ++
    ({ 
        headers: attributes.headers 
        ++ 
        { 
            xpto: p("secure::SOME-VALUE")
        }
    }) 
)
as Object {
    class: "org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes"
}
```

Now I am getting below error:

> ""Exception happen while calling 'class
> org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributesBuilder.build()'
> method. Reason: Errors while creating
> org.mule.runtime.api.util.SerializableLazyValue by reflection, even
> when class in on classpath.'
>
> 5| (attributes | ... 19| }
>
> Trace: at main (line: 5, column: 5)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
> output application/java --- ( (attributes - "headers" -
> "maskedRequestPath") ++ ({ headers: attributes.headers ++ { xpto:
> p("secure::SOME-VALUE") } }) ) as Object { class:
> "org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes" }"."

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the field `clientCertificate` is creating problem. You can try removing them like you did with `maskedRequestPath`. Also want to mention that if you are using Mule 4.3 or later you can reduce your DataWeave using [`update` operator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-operators#update-operator)

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
((attributes - "maskedRequestPath" - "clientCertificate") update {
    case .headers.xpto! -> p("secure::SOME-VALUE")
}) as Object {
    class: "org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes"
}
```